# Getting recently updated packages

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, package

**Use case:**

Imagine there is the following `package.json`:

```
{
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "name": "my-app",
  "devDependencies": {
    "connect-modrewrite": "*",
    "csslint": "~0.10.0",
    "eslint": "*",
    ...
}
```

And `eslint` maintainers issued a new package update, which my daily build task has installed via `npm install` among other packages. And suddenly the build task fails.

Now, while researching the reasons for a build failure, I want to know if there was a dependency package update that could be a culprit of a daily build failure.

**Desired result/output:**

```
eslint             0.15.0 02/15/2015
connect-modrewrite 0.2.0  01/15/2015
...
```

Basically, I need a list of my project dependencies with a version date. Is it possible to get this kind of meta information with `npm` or a third-party tool like `npm-check`?

---

There is a [Recently updated packages](https://www.npmjs.com/browse/updated) page which is exactly what I'm looking for, but in the context of my `package.json` list of dependencies.

---

I'm aware about the "avoid surprises" best practices that suggest to list an exact version number for every dependency and upgrade packages cautiously and on-demand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can query npm registry for info on packages using [`view` npm command](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/view). You can even pass in json field you are interested in (looks like `time.modified` will help in your case).

Combine that with some shell pipes and utilities like [`jq`](http://stedolan.github.io/jq/) and you will get what you need.

```
$ npm view --json eslint | jq ".name, .version, .time.modified" | paste -s
"eslint"    "0.17.1"    "2015-03-18T00:31:26.357Z"
```

Something like this will give you that result on every dependency (as you might guess I am not very good with bash):

```
#!/bin/bash

function trimQuotes {
  echo $@ | cut -c 2- | rev | cut -c 2- | rev
}

function deps {
  trimQuotes `cat package.json | jq '.dependencies | keys | join(" ")'`
}

function info {
  npm view --json $1 | jq '.name, .version, .time.modified' | paste -s
}

function printInfo {
  for word in $@; do
    echo -en "$(trimQuotes $word)\t"
  done;

  echo
}

function main {
  for pkg in $(deps); do
    echo "$(info $pkg)" | while read line; do
      printInfo $line
    done;
  done;
}

main
```

Answer (score 1):

This feature does not currently exist in `npm`.  You can make feature requests at the `npm` issue tracker, https://github.com/npm/npm/issues

One approach to approximate this would be to perform an `npm ls` after each successful daily build and check that into your source control.  Then on a failed daily build you could report the difference between current `npm ls` and last-known-good.

Answer (score 1):

Run the `npm outdated` CLI command **prior** to your daily update.  This will keep a record of what was out of date prior to the install.

[image]

I pipe the output to a file in my repository and use `git diff`.
I commit the before update file and run it again to the output file. Any good source control would work the same way.

This also helps keep track of versions of packages on updated commits.

Comment: This is actually a great idea, thank you! (and definitely it doesn't deserve that downvote).

Comment: Yeah, weird that the downvote went to both of us who did not get the answer marked as accepted. Something to research.

Comment: Yeah, though downvotes were applied before I've marked the answer as correct an awarded the bounty. Anyway, this happens, I appreciate your time and effort. Thanks again!

Comment: It happens.  People use downvotes incorrectly all the time. Thanks for the comment.